# iOS TextInput styles in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Elements such as `<Button/>` and `<TextInput/>` get rendered with default styles on Android but on iOS they are pretty much unstyled. Is there a way to get platform styles (e.g. borders and padding) applied on iOS without reproducing them in CSS?

For example

```
<View style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <Text>Please sign in</Text>
    <TextInput placeholder="Username"/>
    <TextInput placeholder="Password"/>
    <Button onPress={() => {}} title="Sign in"/>
</View>
```

[image: Android screenshot]

[image: iOS screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tombenner/nui

to apply them you can use platform.select